# Python Pandas Feature Generation as aggregate function

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, data-science, feature-engineering

I have a pandas df which is mire or less like

```
        ID  key dist
   0    1   57  1
   1    2   22  1
   2    3   12  1
   3    4   45  1
   4    5   94  1
   5    6   36  1
   6    7   38  1
   .....
```

this DF contains couple of millions of points. I am trying to generate some descriptors now to incorporate the time nature of the data. The idea is for each line I should create a window of lenght x going back in the data and counting the occurrences of the particular key in the window. I did a implementation, but according to my estimation for 23 different windows the calculation will run 32 days. Here is the code

```
def features_wind2(inp):
   all_window = inp
   all_window['window1'] = 0
   for index, row in all_window.iterrows():
      lid = index
      lid1 = lid - 200
      pid = row['key']
      row['window1'] = all_window.query('index < %d & index > %d & key == %d' % (lid, lid1, key)).count()[0]     
   return all_window
```

There are multiple different windows of different length. I however have that uneasy feeling that the iteration is probably not the smartest way to go for this data aggregation. Is there way to implement it to run faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a toy example data frame, you can achieve about a 7x speedup by using `apply()` instead of `iterrows()`.

Here's some sample data, expanded a bit from OP to include multiple `key` values:

```
    ID  key dist
0    1   57  1
1    2   22  1
2    3   12  1
3    4   45  1
4    5   94  1
5    6   36  1
6    7   38  1
7    8   94  1
8    9   94  1
9   10   38  1

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard()
```

Based on these data, and the counting criteria defined by OP, we expect the output to be:

```
    key  dist  window
ID                   
1    57     1       0
2    22     1       0
3    12     1       0
4    45     1       0
5    94     1       0
6    36     1       0
7    38     1       0
8    94     1       1
9    94     1       2
10   38     1       1
```

Using OP's approach:

```
def features_wind2(inp):
    all_window = inp
    all_window['window1'] = 0
    for index, row in all_window.iterrows():
        lid = index
        lid1 = lid - 200
        pid = row['key']
        row['window1'] = all_window.query('index < %d & index > %d & key == %d' % (lid, lid1, pid)).count()[0]     
    return all_window

print('old solution: ')
%timeit features_wind2(df) 

old solution: 
10 loops, best of 3: 25.6 ms per loop
```

Using `apply()`:

```
def compute_window(row):
    # when using apply(), .name gives the row index
    # pandas indexing is inclusive, so take index-1 as cut_idx
    cut_idx = row.name - 1 
    key = row.key
    # count the number of instances key appears in df, prior to this row
    return sum(df.ix[:cut_idx,'key']==key)

print('new solution: ')
%timeit df['window1'] = df.apply(compute_window, axis='columns')

new solution: 
100 loops, best of 3: 3.71 ms per loop
```

Note that with millions of records, this will still take awhile, and the relative performance gains will likely be diminished somewhat compared to this small test case.

**UPDATE**
Here's an even faster solution, using `groupby()` and `cumsum()`. I made some sample data that seems roughly in line with the provided example, but with 10 million rows. The computation finishes in well under a second, on average:

```
# sample data
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = int(1e7)
idx = np.arange(N)
keys = np.random.randint(1,100,size=N)
dists = np.ones(N).astype(int)
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':idx,'key':keys,'dist':dists})
df = df.set_index('ID')
```

Now performance testing:

```
%timeit df['window'] = df.groupby('key').cumsum().subtract(1)

1 loop, best of 3: 755 ms per loop
```

Here's enough output to show that the computation is working:

```
    dist  key  window
ID                   
0      1   83       0
1      1    4       0
2      1   87       0
3      1   66       0
4      1   31       0
5      1   33       0
6      1    1       0
7      1   77       0
8      1   49       0
9      1   49       1
10     1   97       0
11     1   36       0
12     1   19       0
13     1   75       0
14     1    4       1
```

Note: To revert `ID` from index to column, use `df.reset_index()` at the end.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Minor question: How can I utilize the time window in your second solution. [Id_Start - Id End]. I modified the first proposed solution like:
      return sum(df.ix[(cut_idx-window_size):cut_idx,'key']==key)